# SQL Query - Need some basic help

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm in need of some basic TSQL help.  Here's my table layout:

**Orders** Table

- SSN
- ZipCode

**ZipLookup** Table

- ZipCode
- State

All columns are varchars.

How would I get a list of States with the number of distinct SSN's in each state?  Preferably, if a particular SSN has orders from multiple states only the state with the most orders would be counted for that SSN.

Thank you for any tips you can give me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you'd better make sure that you're allowed to be storing SSNs, because there are a whole bunch of privacy laws and regulations that may prohibit it.

The query would look like this:

```
SELECT z.State, COUNT(DISTINCT o.SSN) AS SsnCount
FROM ZipLookup z
INNER JOIN Orders o
    ON o.ZipCode = z.ZipCode
GROUP BY z.State
```

If you need to only count the SSN in its most-frequently-used State:

```
WITH StateSSNs AS
(
    SELECT
        o.SSN, z.State,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM Orders o
    INNER JOIN ZipLookup z
        ON z.ZipCode = o.ZipCode
    GROUP BY o.SSN, z.State
)
SELECT z.State, COUNT(*) AS SsnCount
FROM ZipLookup z
INNER JOIN StateSSNs s
    ON s.State = z.State
WHERE s.RowNum = 1
GROUP BY z.State
```

Performance isn't going to be very good, I think this will require at least one full scan and maybe two, but if you want anything better then you'll need to normalize the schema.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  I actually changed the real column name to SSN so it would be shorter.  :)

Is it possible to write a query where if a particular SSN has orders from multiple states only the state with the most orders would be counted for that SSN?  Like if a particular SSN had 5 orders from NY and 2 orders from KY, only count the ones from NY.

I generally only do simple queries and turn to C# for anything I can't write, but this one seems like it's possible to do in SQL.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Absolutely incredible.  Thank you so much, this is extremely helpful to me.